# Google authentication with django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Im using Django-registration redux to currently allow registration and login , however I want to implement third party login such as google login.

Whats the best way to approach this , preferable a technique which i can use alongside django-registration redux.

Thanks!

Comment: have you done any research by yourself? a basic search gives a couple of tutorials, which point towards using `Python Social Auth`. Have you tried this? it's pretty straight forward.

Comment: Hi , Yes i have done some research and although i didnt find Python Social Auth i did find AllAuth . However Im new to django and python therefore I dont understand if it will work with the current user model or not.